# Python project through cmd with different config files

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, config, configparser

i want to start my python project through a cmd window with different configurations, e.g the function that need different parameter:

```
download.rawData.download(starttime=starttime, endtime=endtime)
```

the starttime and endtime values are from a configfile: (config1.cfg)

```
[Parameter]
starttime=Monday
endtime=Tuesday
```

config2.cfg:

```
[Parameter]
starttime=tuesday
endtime=friday
```

What is the best way to start the project from the cmd like:

```
Python3 project.py --config1 //for time X
Python3 project.py --config2 //for time Y
```

...and so on, of course there are different start and endtimes declared in the config file

The goal is that the configurations for the start- and endtime are not hard-coded in the main project.

What I tried until now:

```
commandLineArgumentParser: ArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-config1", "--config1", help="Config file 1")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-config2", "--config2", help="Config file2")
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()
config1= commandLineArguments.odessa


starttime = config['Parameter']['starttime']
endtime = config['Parameter']['endtime']
```

But this didn´t work
Anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Do you want to simply feed in a command-line argument? Or are you looking for how to schedule commands? What have you tried, and what is your expected behavior?

Comment: What is "best"? Maybe use `configparser` and `argparse` modules to get all the power you may need. But if it's too simple `sys.argv` with or without `configparser`, may be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to run the script multiple times for each parameter. Simply use the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html) module to parse your config file, which you specify on the command line (via the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse) module):

```
import argparse
import configparser

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('config', help="Config file to parse")

args = parser.parse_args()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(args.config)
config.sections()  # Returns ['Parameter']

start = config['Parameter']['starttime']
end = config['Parameter']['endtime']
```

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: thanks for that!
but it gives me an error:
line 35,..., config.read(args.config), AttributeError: 'NamespaceÄ object has not attribute 'config'
What could it be?